# How to make sure that a solution of one differential equation satisfies another in a system of two partial differential equations.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have general question about system of partial differential equations.
Conside a function $\psi = \psi(x,y)$ and a system two partial differential equtions
$$
 \psi_{xx} + \psi_{x} = F \tag{1}
$$
$$
\psi_{yy} + \psi_{y} = G \tag{2}
$$
where $\psi_z= \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial z}$ denotes the partial derivate and $F=F(x,y),G=G(x,y)$ are functions of $x,y$.

Now consider having the solution of the equation (1), let's denote the solution of equations (1) as $\psi^{(1)}$ i.e.
$
 \psi^{1}_{xx} + \psi^{1}_{x} = F 
$
holds.

The question I have is what do I plug into the equation (2).
At first glance, it seems to me, that any part of $\psi$ purely dependent on on $y$ would be derivatived to zero, so that I should plug in $\psi = \psi^1 + f(y)$ so that
$$ 
\psi_{yy} + \psi_{y} = \psi^{(1)}_{yy} + f_y + \psi^{(1)}_{yy} + f_{yy}
$$
where, again $f = f(y)$. Now I would plug this into $(2)$ and try to solve it.

But this seems problematic, as if I would first solve the equation (2), the solution would have the form $\psi(x,y) = \psi^{(2)}(x,y) + f(x)$, where I denoted $\psi^{(2)}$ as the solution of equations (2).
This "asymmetry" doesn't look good, since the order of solving partial differential equation should surely not impact the form of the solution of a system of equations.

So the question is, if I have solution of one of the equations (1) or (2), what should I plug in into the second unsolved equations to ensure that both equations are satisfied?

Comment: In this particular instance, you can integrate both equations using an integrating factor 
\begin{align} 
e^{x} \psi_{x} &= f_{1}(y) + \int e^{x} F(x, y) dx & \implies \psi &= f_{2}(y) + \int e^{-x} \left( f_{1}(y) + \int e^{x} F(x, y) dx \right) dx \\ 
e^{y} \psi_{y} &= g_{1}(x) + \int e^{y} G(x, y) dy & \implies \psi &= g_{2}(x) + \int e^{-y} \left( g_{1}(x) + \int e^{y} G(x, y) dy \right) dy \end{align}
You can then determine the conditions on $F, f_{1}, f_{2}, G, g_{1}, g_{2}$ such that the equations are satisfied.